# Using the right event observer name issue in the admin area

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I would like to some custom things when you are on the create a new website in the admin area page.

This is the exact controller used to render that page:

```
\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Store\NewWebsite::execute
```

and this is the content of the `adminhtml/events.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_system_store_newwebsite">
        <observer name="custom_name"
                  instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Custom" />
    </event>
</config>
```

I am looking for the right event name. I tried several variations like:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_system_store_newwebsite
controller_action_postdispatch_system_store_newWebsite
controller_action_postdispatch_admin_system_store_newwebsite
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_store_newWebsite
```

None of them are working. I am trying to get the full action name. This is from the docs:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_{full_action_name} – executes after a controller with specific {full_action_name}.
```

The route defined in the : `vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` is: `admin`
. See:

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="adminhtml" frontName="admin">
        <module name="Magento_Backend" />
    </route>
</router>
```

Would you please help out, to get the right event name ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found out a way how to get the right event name, using the `controller_action_postdispatch` event.

Using the following code, in your observer:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $requestInterface;
     
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $requestInterface
    ) {
        $this->requestInterface = $requestInterface;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
         $fullName = $this->requestInterface->getFullActionName();
         echo $fullName; exit(); // this will the exact `full action name`
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

> create file etc/events.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_system_store_newwebsite">
        <observer name="custom_name"
                  instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Custom" />
    </event>
</config>
```